# How do I create a section that has a background image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a page that has different sections, the first section showing the menu and a background image and then there being a white section under it which has the height of e.g. 500px.

For some reason I can't seem to get my image to fit in a good way.
And right now it's not even showing me the image and I'm not sure why.

How do I make the image fit the screen and then add a white section under it that I can scroll to?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


#firstSection {
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/xZjqUcR.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 700px;
}


#secondSection {
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>


    <section id="nav-bar">

    </section>

    <section id="firstSection">

    </section>

    <section id="secondSection">

    </section>

</body>
```

This is what I am trying to achieve, and if you scroll down there should be a section that is 500px tall.

[image]

Comment: Replace your "section"s with `div`.

Comment: change `background-image` to `background` or remove the no-repeat

Comment: @EGC section is a block element, no need to set width:100%

Comment: @EGC that also cuts off like 40% of the image

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the `background-size` to `auto 100%` and put the background on the right:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#firstSection {
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/xZjqUcR.png") right no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

#secondSection {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<section id="nav-bar">

</section>

<section id="firstSection">

</section>

<section id="secondSection">

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of mistakes in your snippet. Firstly, in order to use bootstrap, you have to include jquery first - this caused a script error in the snippet (maybe not locally!)

The reason the image was not displaying was because you had the setting for `background-repeat` in the same line as `background-image`; if you want to list your settings in one line, just use `background`.

You may have better results using contain rather than cover. Also I would set a body width in the css. See snippet.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


body {
  width: 100%;
}

#firstSection {
  height: 700px;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/xZjqUcR.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  /*or put these on one line using background: url etc no-repeat contain*/
}

#secondSection {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section id="nav-bar">

</section>

<section id="firstSection">

</section>

<section id="secondSection">

</section>
```

Comment: But the image doesnt take up the full width of the browser? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @RileyVarga because you are specifying a height in your section CSS, the image width  will be sized accordingly, like setting width to auto. If you want it to be 100 percent width of the browser, remove the height setting, and put in width: 100%. You could experiment with a max height but put the width attribute first, and the max height at the end after the background attributes. I did wonder about the height CSS when I first saw the code.   Good luck.